# Expected number of steps in a 1D random walk with reflecting edges

Tags: expected-value

Assume there is a row of $k$ tiles. A creature (monkey in some situations, ant in others, frog in others) lies on tile $a$. There is a 50% probability that the creature jumps to tile $a-1$ and a 50% probability that the creature jumps to tile $a+1$, unless it is on an edge tile. If it is on an edge tile, it must jump inwards, so it can't escape the system (i.e. tile 2 from tile 1 and tile $k-1$ from tile $k$). What is the expected number of steps for it to first reach tile $b$? $1<=a, b<=k$ is assumed. I feel like Markov chains might be used to get the answer, but I have a very limited understanding of them. If there is a closed form for the answer as well as a derivation for understanding, that would be perfect.

Comment: Markov chains are the way!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you elaborate in an answer how to use them in order to solve this problem? Like I said, I have a limited understanding of them.

Comment: I'have taken the liberty to modifiy your title and tags (3 tags are a good average)  in order more readers are directed towards this interesting question and its interesting answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly (to me) there happens to be a very simple expression for the expected number of steps to reach $\ b\ $ from $\ a\ $. For $\ a < b\ $, it is:
$$
\left(\,b + a -2\,\right)\,\left(\,b-a\,\right)\ .
$$
Although a Markov chain is the obvious way to model the process, and I'm sure it *could* used to derive the above result, there turns out to be a less cumbersome way of doing it.

For each $\ i\ $ between $\ 1\ $ and $\ b\ $ inclusive, let $\ e_i\ $ be the expected number of steps the creature takes to go from $\ i\ $ to $\ b\ $. Obviously, $\ e_b\ = 0\ $.

If the creature starts from $\ 1\ $, then it has to take one step to $\ 2\ $, from which the expected number of steps to reach $\ b\ $ is $\ e_2\ $.  Thus, the expected number of steps, $\ e_1\ $, to reach $\ b\ $ from $\ 1\ $ is $\ e_2 + 1\ $.

If the creature starts from $\ b-1\ $, then with probability $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ it reaches $\ b\ $ on the very next step—that is, in just a single step—, and with probability  $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ it jumps to $\ b-2\ $, from which the expected number of steps to reach $\ b\ $ is $\ e_{b-2}\ $.  Thus $\ e_{b-1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(e_{b-2} +1\right) + \frac{1}{2}\,1=\frac{1}{2}\,e_{b-2}+1\ $.

If the creature starts from any other point $\ i\ $, with $\ 2\le i\le b-2\ $, then with probability $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ it jumps to $\ i-1\ $, from which the expected number of steps to reach $\ b\ $ is $\ e_{i-1}\ $, and with probability $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ it jumps to $\ i+1\ $, from which the expected number of steps to reach $\ b\ $ is $\ e_{i+1}\ $. Therefore, $\ e_i = \frac{1}{2}\left(e_{i-1} +1\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(e_{i+1} +1\right)= \frac{1}{2}\,e_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2}\,e_{i+1} +1\ $.

Putting this all together, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
e_1 &=& e_2 + 1\\
e_i &=& \frac{1}{2}\,e_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2}\,e_{i+1} +1, \ \ \mbox{for } i=2,3, \dots, b-2\ \mbox{, and}\\
e_{b-1} &=& \frac{1}{2}\,e_{b-2}+1\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
or, equivalently,

\begin{eqnarray}
e_1 - e_2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &=&  1\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -\frac{1}{2}\,e_{i-1} + e_i -\frac{1}{2}\,e_{i+1} &=& 1, \ \ \mbox{for } i=2,3, \dots, b-2\ \mbox{, and}\\
-\frac{1}{2}\,e_{b-2}+e_{b-1} &=& 1\ .
\end{eqnarray}

These equations can be written as:
$$
M\,e = \mathbb 1\ ,
$$
where $\ M\ $ 
is the $\ \left(\,b-1\,\right)\times\left(\,b-1\,\right)\ $ matrix, and $\ \mathbb 1\ $ the $\ \left(\,b-1\,\right)\times\,1\ $ column vector, whose entries are given by:
\begin{eqnarray}
M_{1,2} &=& -1\\
M_{i,i} &=& 1\ \ \mbox{for } i=1,2,\dots, b-1\\
M_{i,i-1} &=& -\frac{1}{2}\ \ \mbox{for } i=2,3,\dots, b-1\\
M_{i,i+1} &=& -\frac{1}{2}\ \ \mbox{for } i=2,3,\dots, b-2\\
M_{i,\,j} &=& 0 \ \ \mbox{for all other }\ i, j\\
\mathbb 1_i &=& 1\ \ \mbox{for } i=1,2,\dots, b-1\ . 
\end{eqnarray}
For $\ b=6\ $, the matrix $\ M\ $ looks like this:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1&-1&0&0&0 \\
      -\frac{1}{2}&1&-\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\
 0&-\frac{1}{2}&1&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0&0&-\frac{1}{2}&1&-\frac{1}{2}\\
0&0&0&-\frac{1}{2}&1&
\end{matrix}\right)\ ,$$
and has the following inverse:
$$
M^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 5&8&6&4&2\\
                              4&8&6&4&2\\
                              3&6&6&4&2\\
                              2&4&4&4&2\\
                              1&2&2&2&2\\
\end{matrix}\right)\ .
$$
From this, we can conjecture that the entries of the inverse of the $\ \left(\,b-1\,\right)\times\left(\,b-1\,\right)\ $ matrix $\ M\ $, defined above, should be the matrix $\ L\ $ whose entries are given by:
\begin{eqnarray}
L_{i,1} &=& b-i\ \ \mbox{for } i=1,2,\dots, b-1\\
L_{1,\,j} &=& 2\,\left(b-j\right)  \ \mbox{for } j=2,3,\dots, b-1\\
L_{i,\,j} &=& 2\,\min\left(b-i,b-j\right) \ \mbox{for } 2\le i\le b-1\ \ \mbox{and }\ 2\le j\le b-1\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
and on checking the product $\ M\,L\ $, we find that it is indeed the $\ \left(\,b-1\,\right)\times\left(\,b-1\,\right)\ $ identity matrix.  So, finally, we have:
$$
e = M^{-1}\,\mathbb 1 = L\,\mathbb 1\ ,
$$
and $\ e_a\ $, the expected number of steps to get to $\ b\ $ from $\ a\ $ is the sum of the entries in the $\ a^\mbox{th}\ $ row of $\ L\ $:
\begin{eqnarray}
e_a &=& \left(b-a\right) + 2\,\left(\,a-1\,\right)\,\left(\,b-a\,\right) + 2\,\sum_{j=1}^{b-a-1} j\\
&=& \left(\,b + a -2\,\right)\,\left(\,b-a\,\right)\ ,
\end{eqnarray}
as stated above.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I think that this is just a disguised Markov chain, as your "M" is the identity matrix minus the transition matrix.

Comment: Not quite. The identity matrix minus the transition matrix is a *singular* $\ b\times b\ $ matrix.  $\ M\ $ is the submatrix obtained from it by chopping off its last row and column.  But you're right that there is indeed a Markov chain lurking in the shadows.